# MongoDB security using createUser

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to implement security in MongoDb. By adding an user with:

```
> db.addUser('admin','mypassword')
```

results in:

```
WARNING: The 'addUser' shell helper is DEPRECATED. Please use 'createUser' instead
```

From the documentation I've tried using the createUser function instead:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
    {
      user: "superuser",
      pwd: "12345678",
      roles: [ "root" ]
    }
)
```

Restart the DB with --dbauth.
Now, when I try to connect and authenticate with the above user, an error is returned:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
connecting to: test
> db.auth('superuser','12345678')
Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 }
```

On the other hand, this works, but it is not a good idea to show the user/password in the process list:

```
mongo -u superuser -p 12345678 --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Any help???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The in-shell authentication is performed against the test database, whereas the user has been created in the admin database. It should work if you add an use statement before db.auth

```
> use admin
> db.auth('superuser','12345689');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So if I understand correctly, I should start all my mongo shell activity with the above two statements. Then I can use my databases, right ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, although you may want to set up a limited user with a readwrite role for production use.